# writing file into subdirectory in internal storage, how?

Tags: android, save, fileoutputstream

The following line corresponds to the path trying to streamOutput my info,
Files-->a-->b-->c
i am able to add files by not write into it. would be glad to get some help.

Thanks a lot and have a great day